# What is the correct way to embed a resource in a reusable MFC class?

Tags: class, mfc, resource-files

I am writing a C++ (MFC in particular) class which uses an external .gif image file and produces another image file after some processing. It would be nice if the initial image could be embedded in the code somehow. I have read in MSDN about using multiple .rc files and the whole thing seems quite complicated.

I would like to know from people who have gone through this before how to handle this problem.

**EDIT** : Sorry I was not clear. The class I am writing should be standalone, so I could use it again. If I put the image in a resource file, then the class will not compile if used in a fresh project.

Comment: Are ou looking to embed the second generated file into the .exe at runtime or at compile time? At compile time you can always import the gif into the resource file and use it in your code. At runtime you cant really do it and only way is to read it from disk

Comment: What are you using to read the gif?

Comment: @MarkRansom : I am using the CImage::Load() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embedd MFC resources inside a class or similar C++ container. They can only be embedded in DLL or EXE files - in a separate section of the produced binary. Since you want your class to be reusable, you must put it in a DLL. Hence, you must tag your class with the [AFX_EXT_CLASS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xyb5w93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword.

There are two solutions.

**Solution #1:**

- Create an MFC DLL project (`MFC Extension DLL`). Call it `MyLibrary` or whatever.
- Put all your standalone classes in this DLL.
- Embed all necessary resources.
- Let your classes load resources from the `HINSTANCE` of your DLL as described below.

There are several ways to retrieve the `HINSTANCE` of your DLL. If you ask me, the best solution is to grab it in `DllMain`. This is done automatically if you choose the `MFC Extension DLL` configuration:

```
static AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE MyLibDLL = { NULL, NULL }; // Make this variable global!
// Then access the hInstance as follows:
LoadResource(MyLibDLL.hModule, ...)
```

**Solution #2:**

Store your resource as a byte buffer. Or better, convert it to [Base64](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=base64&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CFcQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64&ei=uRIqUOCIOarg4QTS84CYDg&usg=AFQjCNFxJAMXAr4Jc-0wQvhcp_q4nZlf5w) and store it as an ASCII string. But remember not to blow the stack! Keep your resources small or increase the stack size in your project settings. Example:

```
const char *encodedResource = "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh";
char *data = decode(encodedResource);
foo(data);
```

Comment: May I ask which solution you chose?

Answer (score 1):

In the solution explorer go to resource view, Right click and click `Add Resource` then click `Import` and add the gif file. Now you can use your `Resource ID` to access the gif file in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the file to a resource doesn't embed the file in the actual resource file it just links to the file. If you open your .rc file you'll see it says something like:

```
IDB_GIF_MYIMAGE     GIF     "artwork\\mygif.gif"
```

During the compilation face the resource will be included in the EXE, which you reference using the resource id `IDB_GIF_MYIMAGE`. You can reference the same file in other projects without having to duplicate the file.

Comment: Yes but a new project will have its own .rc file, and the resource will not be included unless it is manually inserted.

Comment: There's no #pragma that I'm aware of that allows you to include a resource by just specifying it in a .h or .cpp file. Therefore unless you're willing to modify the .rc file OR load the image by path (rather than embedded resource) your only option would be to BASE64 the image and include it as text, which would be a nightmare to manage.

Answer (score 0):

To embed an image (or any other type of binary data) into your class without using resource files, use the bin2c utility, for example you can download it from here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-16/libpcap/msdos/bin2c.c . Running this on a file will produce what is basically a static array with the bytes of the file as members of that array. Stuff this array into a .h file (or put it in the header of your class, or make it a static member...) and then you will have that file available in-memory without having to use LoadResource() and its brethren.

If you want to use this with CImage::Load(), you will have to write your own class that derives from IStream, and implement a few of the methods in a way so that they 'read' from memory. I don't know of any ways to let CImage decode an image from an in-memory representation of a gif file.

Comment: I am aware of this method. What I am looking for is a cleaner and more practical way to embed the image. AFAIK handling of a byte array image  is not very convenient.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cleaner and more practical'? What about this method does not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: You state in your question that you don't want to put the image in a resource, because then you need to #include that other resource in your resource section when you include your class in another project. Yet you do want to use the resource editor to edit or view the image. You can't have it both ways - either you put the image in a separate resource file and #include that into resource section of every project you want to use it it, or you put the image in code, in which case you won't be able to use the resource editor to view it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is just to document that to use the class you must also import to your project a certain .gif file and give it a certain expected identifier (e.g. IDB_MYCLASS_MYGIF).  You can then use the preprocessor to detect if the resource has been correctly added, e.g.:

```
#ifndef IDB_MYCLASS_MYGIF
    #error Make sure you import mygif.gif to the project.  See docs for more info.
#endif
```

This will prevent the class compiling until the user imports the image properly.  Alternatively you could just use #ifdefs to fall back to code which does not use the default image if it is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CRuntimeDialog class presented in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5371/ToDoList-6-5-4-Feature-Release-An-effective-and-fl . It provides a way to create a dialog from the string that makes up the resource definition.